# Problem with tikz and pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have received some LaTeX code from a colleague which compiles successfully on his computer but not on mine. I get the following error messages (some of them more than once):

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/fill' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

! Package tikz Error: Unknown coordinate system 'ticklabel'.

! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `near' (in 'near ticklabel').

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/legend pos' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

I have tried finding an answer online but have not been successful. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you compare the versions of pgfplots on both computers?

Comment: No not yet. I have version 1.2.2, and I guess it might be out of date. I have no idea how to update it however. I'm using Ubuntu, and I'm relying on synaptic to keep the packages up to date. Maybe not such a good idea?

Comment: @MartinKidd: Current up-to-date version of [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) is `1.7`. I suggest an update. See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)